# "This inspection detects instance attribute definition outside __init__ method" PyCharm

Tags: python, class, pycharm

I'm using the following class to connect and create a cursor within a firebase database:

```
class Firebird:

    username= "..."
    password= "..."

    def __init__(self, archive):
        self.archive = archive

   def connect(self):
       try:
           self.connection = connect(dsn=self.archive, user=self.username, password=self.password)
       except Error, e:
           print "Failed to connect to database", e
           exit(0)
```

And the PyCharm is warning me: "This inspection detects instance attribute definition outside **init** method", in the `self.connection` assign.

Is it a bad practice assign properties to the instance outside of `__init__`? In this case, what could i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's generally considered a good practice to explicitly define/declare all your attributes in the `__init__` function, this way you have a quick list of all used (or unused) attributes in the class.

```
class Firebird:

    username= "..."
    password= "..."

    def __init__(self, archive):
        self.archive = archive
        self.connection = None

   def connect(self):
       try:
           self.connection = connect(dsn=self.archive, user=self.username, password=self.password)
       except Error, e:
           print "Failed to connect to database", e
           exit(0)
```

Comment: If you use `from pystrict import strict \n @strict \n class Firebird: ...`, then it will be a runtime error to create attrs outside of init.